# Sort array of complex object by date in string format

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

I need to sort this array called gridObj, by key.expiry.value.

[image: object to sort]

I tried the following with no result:

```
const sorted = Object.keys(gridObj).map((val) => gridObj[val]?.expiry?.sort((a, b) => {
    const aa = a.value.split('/').reverse();
    const bb = b.value.split('/').reverse();
    return (aa > bb) - (aa < bb);
  }));
```

What am I doing bad?
I tried the other solutions on StackOverflow but no one has helped me

I want this

```
gridObj = [
    "11566260": [
        expiry: {
            header: "Expiry",
            value: "14/08/2023"
        }
    ],
    "11566261": [
        expiry: {
            header: "Expiry",
            value: "10/08/2023"
        }
    ],
]
```

to become this:

```
gridObj = [
    "11566261": [
        expiry: {
            header: "Expiry",
            value: "10/08/2023"
        }
    ],

    "11566260": [
        expiry: {
            header: "Expiry",
            value: "14/08/2023"
        }
    ],
]
```

Comment: Would you be able to include a small set of test data as text. That helps a lot. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes! Added to the question

Answer (score -1):

Your data is a little finicky. There is room for error here when one of the assumptions does not hold. (more than one key, more than one item in the array etc)

```js
gridObj.sort((a, b) => {
  const aa = new Date(a[Object.keys(a)[0]][0].expiry.value);
  const bb = new Date(b[Object.keys(b)[0]][0].expiry.value);
  return (aa > bb) - (aa < bb);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data is indeed a bit unusual. You will not be able to use Array.sort as the array is zero-length. So you need to transform it info an array, sort it and transform it back to the initial "array" (basically an array with some properties).
This code should do:

```
Object.keys(gridObj) // get all the keys
    .map(e=> ({key: e, val: gridObj[e]})) // transform it into key-value tuples so we can sort the array by date 
    .sort((a, b) => {
         const aa = a.val.expiry.value.split('/').reverse(); // [YYYY, MM, MMDD] 
         const bb = b.val.expiry.value.split('/').reverse();
         return  (aa > bb) - (aa < bb); // convert arrays to string and compare
    }).reduce((acc, crt) => { // transform sorted tuples into sorted array
         acc[crt.key] = crt.val; 
         return acc
    }, Array()) // pass an empty array as accumulator
```